# my movie code in java

Tags: java, information-hiding

I'm only a beginner and I am having some struggles.

this is for a uni assignment, I've had to make a a movie database and have to have four different classes. (i.e movie, playlist, movie database, interface).

I've constructed my movie code. within this code, it says that we have make it so its not case sensitive (I've done this successfully) this is for movie names and for director name of movie. however, with this, compiling and running the code, it works. but if I'm typing in that the director of movie1 and movie 2 are the same. it exits the program run. but I don't want this.

```
if(directorMatch = director1.equalsIgnoreCase( director2)){

          System.out.println ("Director already entered");
        }
```

this is the code that I have put in. throughout my code, there is no system.exit (0).

for the movie data base, I will have to store a list of movies here (i.e movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4). this will obviously feed off the movie.java code. I'm looking in my notes and I keep coming back to encapsulation (information hiding), is this where I should I be looking or should I be looking somewhere else??

we can't use arrays in the assignment.

I'm sorry this is a long one.

thank you for all the help

Cass

Comment: You asked the same unclear thing hours ago. You got some feedback. And now you come back with almost the same stuff. Sorry, but it doesn't work this way. If your assignment is so unclear ... talk to your instructors. If they refuse, then you probably should look into the material they gave to you. SO is not a replacement for doing that **learning** thing!

Comment: Please show us all your code. My first guess is that your code is returning (e.g. because your if-then logic falls through) in a way that you didn't anticipate.

Comment: for test equals you can hust do if(director1.equalsIgnoreCase( director2)) and then if is true that will print what you want!!

Comment: @C.Bachen Please give some more code. How are you typing that their directors are the same ? m1.director=m2.director="Steven Spielberg"; Whats your construct, your classes ?